# Pixel handling in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Like in iPhone we have a standard pixel sized of 320*480 to work with on the screen. What are the specifications for Android based devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different Android devices with many different screen sizes. You can read the official documentation for advice on how to handle these variations.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

The variety is to large to limit your app like that. On iPhone you have two devices (now, also iPad), here you have a limitless number.
You would better use the DPI (density independent pixel) and also scale your image to the screen dimensions (gathered at run-time)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html